# Flutter failed for task app:mergeDebugNativeLibs and app:mergeDebugJavaResource

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> File 'com.android.builder.files.ZipCentralDirectory@6f58452a' was deleted, but previous version not found in cache

- 

## Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> File 'com.android.builder.files.ZipCentralDirectory@48b70346' was deleted, but previous version not found in cache

- 

## Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 23s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        23.9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 15):

Try any one of the following steps:

1. Goto Files > Click `Invalidate Caches/Restart`
2. Restart your machine
3. On terminal write **flutter clean** and then **flutter run**

Comment: How do you invalidate caches?

Comment: @HudsonKim In Android Studio go to File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart and then select Invalidate and Restart button.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Code Editor. How to use invalidate caches? Please suggest.

Comment: @Kamlesh Then try the other 2 steps.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue after setting up my flutter project to run on iOS. When I tried to run it back on Android, this error was thrown.

This worked for me (on Windows):

1. Close your project and close your code editor
2. Open Task Manager
3. Finish all vscode-related tasks you see (or related to the IDE you are using)
4. Finish all Java-related tasks, inclidung **OpenJDK Platform binary** (there are usually two of these; finish both)
5. Go to your project's root folder and delete the **build** folder
6. Open your project again and run

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Let's make it easier:-

Please take this as a rule: Never edit your gradles and build files manually **especially** when you're working on cross-platform development.

You can solve this issue by:-

Step 1:-

[image]

Step 2:-

[image]

Step 3:-

[image]

That's it. fingers crossed.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was enough to exclude only path  **'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'** on
*android/app/build.gradle*

```
android {
  ......
  defaultConfig
  {
   ......
   multiDexEnabled true
  }
  packagingOptions 
  {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude("META-INF/*") 
  }
 dependencies {
  .......
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1' 
 }          
}
```

###### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    .......
    android:name="androidx.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
```

Now

- run **flutter clean**
- run **flutter get**

It's worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me before i solved it by the following steps:
 
1- Updating the program 
2- Updating flutter
3- Copying the files from old project to a new one

Answer (score 0):

The problem is one of the plugins.Usually related to contacts.
Flutter has a problem with this package. If you are using the latest version, try the previous versions

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your terminal
2. Go to your project directory
3. Type the commands `flutter clean` then `flutter run`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

I had to go into my project folder and I renamed the "build" folder to "build.old" and the ".dart_tool" to ".dart_tool.old".

I was then able to run the command "flutter clean" from a command prompt at the root of my project folder.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, this happens when the `build` cache gets out of sync. To fix:

- run `flutter clean`
- delete the `build` folder
- run `flutter get`

If this doesn't do the trick, try running `flutter pub cache clean` before the steps above.

Answer (score 0):

```
android {  

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
    }
}
```

Add this in :

android/app  --> build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, I followed the steps above,

Invalidate Caches/Restart, I restarted and then error:

Flutter failed to delete a directory at "build\flutter_assets". The flutter tool cannot access the file or directory.
Please ensure that the SDK and/or project is installed in a location that has read/write permissions for the current user.

Appeared, but just deleted the build
I run "flutter run" on terminal and it worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).