# What can be possible solution for " Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'. " while running flutter app

Tags: flutter

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> File 'com.android.builder.files.ZipCentralDirectory@15d7a122' was deleted, but previous version not found in cache

Comment: you solved this?

Comment: yes sir, I got solution for it

Comment: @MansiMandlik in case it is another solution as stated in [Flutter failed for task app:mergeDebugNativeLibs and app:mergeDebugJavaResource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62760392/flutter-failed-for-task-appmergedebugnativelibs-and-appmergedebugjavaresource) , you should tell the solution. :)